# SQL object types and Oracle's XMLType

Tags: sql, xml, database, oracle

I'm studying how to make, or at least generate and use, XML Schemas for the purpose of using Oracle's XML DB and all of the technologies and benefits that come with it (XPath, structured storage, etc.)

I'm a little confused though. You can obviously create a regular object type, say like this...

```
CREATE TYPE my_obj AS OBJECT (
   num INTEGER,
   name VARCHAR2(32),
   ...
   );
```

But let's say I'm trying to replace object types with XMLTypes. First, to reap the indexing performance gains, you need to generate a schema, or write one yourself.

A perfect example of this is in Oracle's documentation, see the schema right before the structure given in this link:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10790/xdb03usg.htm#BABJFFEG

That seems perfect for what I want. Nested insertions are taken care of, object-oriented features are there with the XML schema restriction attribute, etc. Now take a look at this one...

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10790/xdb03usg.htm#BABBGIED

That schema has "annotations" in it, referencing "SQLTypes," which are--presumably--Oracle abstract data types. This is where I'm confused. Why go through the extra complexity to convert your storage to schema-based XMLType storage if you still need to create SQLTypes to do it in the Oracle system?

See automatic Oracle XML schema generation example here: 
 `http://roman-oblak.blogspot.com/2010/01/changing-xsd-schema-to-oracle-xsd.html`

Answer (score 0):

"**Structured storage**" means you upload an XML document and XMLDB will insert the contents into *relational* tables. Updates of parts of the document are done very efficiently by updating these tables and you can do all sorts of queries which are not possible using XPath. - It's sort of a built-in ORM.

"**Unstructured storage**" would keep your XML as-is. You'll still have the option to index on XPaths, so retrieval of portions of huge XMLs could be fast. With Oracle 11 you can also store the XML in binary (parsed) format, which would be even faster and smaller.

You might want to review this [Oracle White Paper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/xmldb/xmldb-store-12cr1-2043451.pdf) about choosing the best XMLType 
storage option for your use case.